# Почему в этом случае происходит потеря значения this?

Tags: javascript, объекты, this

Читаю об этом на [learn.js](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods#vnutrennyaya-realizatsiya-ssylochnyy-tip) и ничего не понимаю.

Можно ли как-то простыми словами объяснить почему во втором случае происходит потеря значения `this`?

```js
let user = {
    name: "Джон",
    hi() { console.log(this.name); },
    bye() { console.log("Пока"); }
};

user.hi(); // вызов метода работает хорошо
(user.name == "Джон" ? user.hi : user.bye)(); // Ошибка!
```

Тут, насколько я понимаю, если значение свойства `name` Джон, то происходит выбор первого значения - `user.hi`. Дальше открываются скобки и происходит запуск метода объекта.

Чем глобально первый запуск отличается от второго? Первый выглядит так: `user.hi()`. Второй в итоге будет выглядеть так: `(user.hi())`.

Comment: в первом запуск метода идёт у экземпляра объекта. Т.е. внутри скоупа. Во-втором передаётся ссылка на функцию, а скоуп глобальный.....вот и всё. привязывать надо через bind

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский а где во втором передается ссылка на функцию? сначала, как я понимаю, просто проверяется условие `user.name == "Джон"` а потом уже выбирается `user.hi`. Когда присваивается эта ссылка?

Comment: Тернарник же что-то возвращает. правильно?

Comment: Просто говоря - разные контексты. Когда вызваете у объекта user.hi() - видит name т.к. он есть у объекта, а когда вы передаёте функцию user.hi то контекст у неё меняется на window, грубо говоря. если перед этим создать глобальную переменную name - var name = 'Имя' то вы первый раз увидите name из объекта а второй раз name глобальный, т.е. Имя. this просто меняет свой контекст с конкретного объекта на глобальный

Answer (score 6):

`user.hi()` — В первом случае, когда происходит обычный вызов метода, `this` ссылается на **«объект перед точкой»** → `user`;

Этот механизм работает во всех случаях (почти *), где используется вызов `объект.метод();`

---

`(user.name == "Джон" ? user.hi : user.bye)();` — Не одно и то же, что и `(user.hi())` или `(user.hi)()`.

Здесь сначала выполняется выражение внутри скобок, возвращается свойство `hi` из объекта `user` (ссылка на функцию), к которому затем применяется оператор вызова функции `()`

А у ссылки на функцию нет никакого контекста (нет объекта перед точкой, и не важно, откуда была получена ссылка). Т.е. `('x' ? user.hi : user.bye)` всего лишь один из способов получения ссылки. Ошибка будет возникать и в случае обычного копирования в переменную:

```js
"use strict";

let user = {
    hi() { console.log(this.name); },
};

let func = user.hi; // Ссылка на функцию скопирована в переменную func

func(); // У ссылки уже нет никакого контекста (ни точки, ни объекта перед ней)
```

---

`setTimeout(user.hi, 1000)` — тоже частая вариация такой ошибки. Вытащили функцию `hi` из объекта, передали в setTimeout - контекст потерялся.

Правильно: `setTimeout(() => user.hi(), 1000)` — передается функция `() => user.hi()` которая будет вызвана через секунду и сама вызовет `user.hi()`, контекст никуда не денется.

---

** Раз в никогда может возникнуть ситуация, когда в объект попала функция, у которой есть свой жестко привязанный контекст*:

```js
function fn() {
  console.log(this.a);
}

/***/
let obj1 = {
  a: 100,
};

let obj2 = {
  a: 999,
  func: fn.bind(obj1),
}

// Function.bind(obj) создает и возвращает новую функцию, внутри которой
// this всегда будет равен obj, независимо от способа вызова;

obj2.func();
obj2.func.call(obj2);
```

Comment: неправильно говоришь `(user.hi)()` - то же самое что и `(user.hi())`. Из-за этого большая часть объяснения ошибочная. Можешь просто проверить свое утверждение и убедиться, что ты ошибаешься :)

Comment: @Grundy Упс. Спасибо. Неожиданный поворот)

Comment: все потому, что важны не просто скобки, а что внутри них выражение вычисляется.

Comment: @Grundy Что и запутало: `user.hi` ведь тоже "выражение"... где `.` — оператор)

Answer (score 5):

```js
(user.name == "Джон" ? user.hi : user.bye)();
```

Можно считать сокращённой записью для:

```js
let func;
if(user.name == "Джон") func = user.hi;
else func = user.bye;

func(); // контекст вызова потерян
```

Просто в певом случае ссылка на метод сохраняется не в переменную, в как неименованное промежуточное значение, полученное из выражения в скобках.

Comment: Хорошо, но мне непонятно только одно. **Если изменяется контекст выполнения, то что в таком случае что хранит ссылку на функцию?** Вот [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/ajuLetgd/), например, ссылку на метод объекта хранит переменная. А что выступает в качестве "хранителя" здесь? Тернарный оператор?

Comment: Ссылка храниться в чём-то, что так и называется — промежуточное значение. Например, если вы запустите это в консоли: `(true ? 1 : 2)()`, ошибка будет "intermediate value is not a function".

Comment: @Eva, в качестве "хранителя" выступает **результат** выполнения тернарного оператора